# Use JQ to select specific, arbitrarily nested objects from JSON

Tags: json, object, select, nested, jq

I'm looking for efficient means to search through an large JSON object for "sub-objects" that match a filter (via `select()`, I imagine).  However, the top-level JSON is an object with arbitrary nesting contained within, including more simple values, objects and arrays of objects.  For example:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "class": "system",
  "description": "top-level-thing",
  "configuration": {
    "status": "normal",
    "uuid": "id"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "c1",
      "class": "c1",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "c1.1",
          "class": "c1.1"
        },
        {
          "id": "c1.1",
          "class": "FINDME"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "c2",
      "class": "FINDME"
    }
  ],
  "thing": {
    "id": "c3",
    "class": "FINDME"
  }
}
```

I have a solution which does **part of** what I want (and is understandable):

```
jq -r '.. | arrays | .[] | select(.class=="FINDME"?) | .id'
```

which returns:

```
c2
c1.1
```

... however, it misses `c3`, plus it changes the order of items output.  Additionally I'm expecting this to operate on potentially very large JSON structures, I would like to make sure I find an efficient solution.  Bonus points for something that remains readable by `jq` neophytes (myself included).

FWIW, references I was using to help me on the way, in case they help others:

- [Select objects based on value of variable in object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq)
- [How to use jq to find all paths to a certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800718/how-to-use-jq-to-find-all-paths-to-a-certain-key)
- [Recursive search values by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459429/recursive-search-values-by-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a streaming-parser solution. To make sense of it, you'll need to read up on the `--stream` option, but the key is that the output includes lines of the form: [PATH, VALUE]

#### program.jq

```
foreach inputs as $in (null;
  if has("id") and has("class") then null
  else . as $x
  | $in
  | if length != 2 then null
    elif .[0][-1] == "id" then ($x + {id: .[-1]})
    elif .[0][-1] == "class"
         and .[-1] == "FINDME" then  ($x + {class: .[-1]})
    else $x
    end
  end;
  select(has("id") and has("class")) | .id )
```

#### Invocation

```
jq -n --stream -f program.jq input.json
```

#### Output with sample input

```
"c1.1"
"c2"
"c3"
```

Comment: While less readable than the other answer you gave, it does what I want,. including retaining the order, and I'll learn something from it's use.  Thanks.

Comment: Please note the update to remove the assumption. How about posting some details about your file size and comparative timings?

Comment: Thanks for that assumption removing update.  Since the output will likely be slightly different than my example, that bit is helpful.   As for timing, I don't have real data sets yet, so I can't provide that.  I might generate some simulated data sets, and if I do, I'll post a comparison then.

Answer (score 8):

For small to modest-sized JSON input, you're on the right track with `..`
but it seems you want to select `objects`, like so:

```
.. | objects | select(.class=="FINDME"?) | .id
```

For JSON documents that are very large, this might require too much memory, so it may be worth knowing about jq's streaming parser. Unfortunately it's much more difficult to use, so I'd suggest trying the above, and if you're interested, look  in the usual places for documentation about the `--stream` option.

Comment: Well, that should have been obvious - I'll use this option until I run into performance issues.