# Use jq to filter content by a certain key, but no output

Tags: json, filter, key, jq

I have similar question as [how-to-use-jq-to-find-all-paths-to-a-certain-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800718/how-to-use-jq-to-find-all-paths-to-a-certain-key/) and also checked the accepted answer.

The solution described in answer works for the exactly same input as [the ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800718/how-to-use-jq-to-find-all-paths-to-a-certain-key/), but after I updated the json a little bit as following (remove last foo part), I can't get any output by filter:

```
fromstream(tostream | select(.[0]|index("foo")))
```

The updated input json:

```
{
    "A": {
      "A1": {
        "foo": {
          "_": "_"
        }
      },
      "A2": {
        "_": "_"
      }
    },
    "B": {
      "B1": {}
    }
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
{
    "A": {
      "A1": {
        "foo": {
          "_": "_"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But I got nothing. You can check here https://jqplay.org/s/s21FFUeoQz0.

I've also tried the filter without **fromstream**:

```
tostream | select(.[0]|index("foo"))
```

The output will be as following, it seems [work here](https://jqplay.org/s/1ZVF5p6WFu_G).

```
[["A","A1","foo","_"],"_"]
[["A","A1","foo","_"]]
[["A","A1","foo"]]
```

So I suspect the **fromstream** has some problem. Can anyone help me figure out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fromstream(tostream | select(length==1 or (.[0]|index("foo"))))
```

Depending on your requirements, you might be able to make things more efficient by wrapping the above expression in a call to `first()`.

—-

FYPI, a less obscure approach would be along the lines of:

```
paths as $p
| select($p[-1]=="foo")
| getpath($p) as $v
| {} | setpath($p;$v)
```

Comment: Cool! it works. Thank you very much for your so quick response. But I can't really understand the magic behind? By adding `length==1 or` will help select more items, even those items without "foo", though it will help `fromstream` to get right output?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
. as $in
| reduce (paths | select(.[-1] == "foo")) as $p (
    null;
    setpath($p; $in | getpath($p))
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6kS_d97ioqU)</sup>

Comment: it also works and easier to understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Who doesn't like obscure, inefficient solutions to problems?

```
delpaths(
    [paths|select(index("foo"))] as $foos
    | [paths|select(. as $p | $foos | map(index($p) != 0) | all)]
)
```

First build a list of all paths containing a "foo" object/property. Then filter all paths leading to these paths. Finally, delete them.